# Highlight bad or wrong close HTML markup on visual studio code

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, markup

I'm currently trying to migrate to Visual Studio Code from Adobe Brackets as a text editor becouse my dev team's environment.

I was able to migrate almost all functionalities I use on Adobe Brackets but I couldn't find a way to replace the function that highlight bad or wrong close markup (As in the Bracket's picture that highlight at the end indicates duplicated `</div>` tag)

[image]

Any user of VSC that know if there is a way to achieve this via native or extention feature? I've search around [Google](https://www.google.com/search?pws=0&biw=956&bih=619&ei=fQADWoSrCISYmQHQ55jQDw&q=highlight+wrong+close+HTML+markup+on+visual+studio+code&oq=highlight+wrong+close+HTML+markup+on+visual+studio+code&gs_l=psy-ab.12...3519214.3523628.0.3524955.15.11.0.0.0.0.598.1980.0j3j4j5-1.8.0....0...1.1j2.64.psy-ab..10.0.0....0.e8-HlBv8ack), the [VSC Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=wrong%20close%20marckup&target=VSCode&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance) and the App Settings but can't find anything...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extension: [HTMLHint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mkaufman.HTMLHint)

Rule (which is true by default anyway):

```json
"tag-pair": true
```

Comment: Thanks alot @Alex, That's exactly what I'm looking for, I found the extension on the marketplace in the past but passed out this rule.